# How to build a chat app in react native using ejabberd

Tags: react-native, chat, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I want to build a **chat** app that has 1-1, and group chat features along with online status,typing indicator,etc in react native that uses ejabberd. I wanted to ask whether I can do it just by using *ejabberd Rest api* calls from my front end.

Also I don't understand how to implement **"typing..."** Feature in react native using ejabberd Rest api.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you'd have to create an xmpp connection and listen on to iq or message as mentioned in the docs for [XEP-0085](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html#example-basic). There are many libraries that would help you do this including [@xmpp/client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@xmpp/client)